# get a websocket message to test it

Tags: python, websocket, pytest

I am quite new to testing web-sockets with pyhton I need to tests an existing code that I cannot change.The code is using websocket-client===0.57.0 a quite old version.
It's possible that I am missing out on a simple fix

Here is the init function for the class :

```
class Client():
    def __init__(self):
        # create websocket connection
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
            url="wss://stream.********:9443/ws/********",
            on_message=self.on_message,
            on_error=self.on_error,
            on_close=self.on_close,
            on_open=self.on_open
        )
```

I need to read the messages received by the web-socket in another test python module  then assert the data values. My issue is that I don't know how to access the it from outside the class. The existing code can access the data inside the class this way :

```
def on_message(self, message):
        data = loads(message)
```

Now I would like to write test with pytest in a separate module here is my code so far that does not work :

```
from **** import Client
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def my_client():
    return Client().ws

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_url(my_client):
    # how can I get the data in this code level???
    # data = my_client??
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the data received by the web-socket outside the class, you can create a new method in the Client class that returns the data.

```
class Client():
    def __init__(self):
        # create websocket connection
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
            url="wss://stream.********:9443/ws/********",
            on_message=self.on_message,
            on_error=self.on_error,
            on_close=self.on_close,
            on_open=self.on_open
        )
        self.data = None

    def on_message(self, message):
        self.data = loads(message)

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data
```

In the above code, I used a new method `get_data` that returns the data received by the web-socket. You can call this method from outside the class to access the data. Here’s how you can use it in your test:

```
from **** import Client
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def my_client():
    return Client()

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_url(my_client):
    client = my_client
    await client.ws.run_forever()
    data = client.get_data()
    # assert data values here
```

I removed the `.ws` from the `my_client` fixture and created a new instance of the Client class in the test. I then called the `run_forever` method on the `ws` object to start the web-socket connection. Finally, I called the `get_data` method to access the data received by the web-socket and asserted the data values.

Comment: No it does not work, data should be get by calling the ws object. You are  just setting data as none so it will keep non as a value.